# How to define (real) code split points with React & Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading

I have a React application with some dependencies that are pretty large but only used on a few pages, so I would now like to split these off into individual bundles (chunks) and load them with Dynamic Imports.

My goal is to define certain points in the code base at which Webpack should move everything that is exclusively used by one side **onto that side**. But I can't get it to do that.

Let me start at the beginning. **Without any additional configuration or Dynamic Imports**, Webpack already splits my code into several chunks, probably because the thresholds for automatic Code Splitting have been reached:

```
File sizes after gzip:

  326.4 KB             build/static/js/2.645b7d9f.chunk.js      <-- some large dependencies already split off
  266.8 KB (+9.72 KB)  build/static/js/main.73cb0e8a.chunk.js
  784 B (-428 B)       build/static/js/runtime-main.dfdb9552.js
  337 B                build/static/css/main.6aa17999.chunk.css
```

This doesn't help me at all as I want to display progress indicators whenever large chunks are lazy-loaded, and that really only works if I am controlling the `Promise`s myself.

So I have **disabled automatic chunk splitting** by setting `optimization.splitChunks` to `false`. This gives me one large chunk and two small standard chunks that don't bother me:

```
File sizes after gzip:

  591.93 KB (+325.13 KB)  build/static/js/main.8b66005b.chunk.js
  784 B                   build/static/js/runtime-main.dfdb9552.js
  337 B                   build/static/css/main.6aa17999.chunk.css
```

Now I add a **Dynamic Import**, and, voila, Webpack creates the named chunk for it, "almost" as expected:

```
  583.29 KB (-8.64 KB)  build/static/js/main.e1a7e462.chunk.js
  10.18 KB              build/static/js/upload.f16a28d9.chunk.js
  1.18 KB (+426 B)      build/static/js/runtime-main.609ffa10.js
  337 B                 build/static/css/main.6aa17999.chunk.css
```

The `import()` statement is inside a button handler, and I was hoping that Webpack would now move all the heavy dependencies that we need to handle this particular button click into one large chunk. But the generated chunk has only 10 kb in size and not the 300 kb that I would expect from looking at the Bundle Analyzer. (It shows me clearly that the button handler is the one crucial connection.)

So I thought: maybe we do need some kind of automatic chunk splitting logic. But after **restoring the Chunk Splitting defaults**, the explicitly created chunk maintains its 10 kb; the dependencies are now shifted into a chunk named "3" of 300kb in size which is again controlled by Webpack:

```
  326.37 KB               build/static/js/3.301c2a98.chunk.js
  257.08 KB (-326.21 KB)  build/static/js/main.2c6d68b0.chunk.js
  10.18 KB                build/static/js/upload.28a98a8d.chunk.js
  1.18 KB (-1 B)          build/static/js/runtime-main.ae96c043.js
  337 B                   build/static/css/main.6aa17999.chunk.css
```

**Honestly, I wouldn't mind leaving this whole work to Webpack**, but then I would at least need access to an event-based API which notifies me whenever additional chunks are getting fetched or finish loading, so that I could show some kind of indication in my app.

Comment: you could try defining multiple entry points depending on how your application is set up. it would generate separate bundles per entry point, and if you set up your chunking right you can include specific things in specific chunks. Like you could put all your React and related libraries into a single chunk, which wouldn't get regenerated much unless you update versions.

Comment: Cache groups with a regex to specify which modules or files you want in a given chunk would probably work ([last example in the docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#split-chunks-example-3)), but would be a pain to manage since that would mean hardcoding this stuff in your Webpack config. IIRC usually if Webpack is putting specific dependencies in non-specific bundles, that means it thinks there's a reason those bundles need those dependencies — maybe transitive dependencies of something else, for example.

Comment: you can also use webpack bundle analyzer to determine exactly which packages get included in each chunk

Comment: Update: got it working as intended by moving the Dynamic Import. Instead of an `import()` in the button handler, I am now `React.lazy()`-loading the entire component that holds the button. That gives me:

```
  251.01 KB        build/static/js/upload.887bf1d2.chunk.js
  195.31 KB        build/static/js/4.a0999ade.chunk.js
  130.42 KB        build/static/js/3.30aae88e.chunk.js
  16.3 KB (+1 B)   build/static/js/main.5bc4d379.chunk.js
  1.19 KB (-10 B)  build/static/js/runtime-main.247f3100.js
  337 B            build/static/css/main.6aa17999.chunk.css
```

Not sure why though???

Comment: After you added the `import()` in the button handler, you must make sure there's no other reference to the heavy dependencies from inside the main chunk, otherwise it might not push all the dependencies to the 'lazy heavy dependencies' you want to have

Comment: @RazRonen, please check my update above; that component is the single crucial connection to the heavy dependencies. When I moved all imports back to the top of that component and lazy-loaded the entire component, it suddenly worked, but it leaves me puzzled. Wondering how other apps with large lazy-loaded dependencies avoid unresponsive UIs if they fully rely on Webpack's lazy-loading. The UI must be unaware of the injected Promises and probably freezing when they're suddenly needed?